# I want to refer to keyboard keys using standard names, but there's no one-size-fits-all

Tags: keyboard

I want to be able to refer to keyboard using with standard, language-independent, but human-readable names.

For instance, if I want to tell someone that Meta + PrtScrn takes a screenshot, I have to refer to both https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee418641(v=vs.85) for Meta (`DIK_LWIN`) and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes for PrtScrn (`VK_SNAPSHOT`).

Consequently, it becomes `DIK_LWIN` + `VK_SNAPSHOT`. This causes whoever is reading it to know two different sets of key naming sets, or to reference two. I'll have better luck just using the English names.

Does anyone know of a solution, like a comprehensive name set? I don't want to use numeric JS KeyCodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how I missed it, but `VK_LWIN` *does* exist. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes might just be the superior—more comprehensive, that is—reference set.